# Passing the name to the action

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am new to coding and I am trying my best, but I am trying to get the gui to submit a name and then have a pop-window say "Your name is:" I know I am missing something obvious, so please be easy on me.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField NametextField;

    public Frame1() {
        setTitle("Confirm Name");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblEnterName = new JLabel("Enter Name:");
        lblEnterName.setBounds(10, 22, 83, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblEnterName);
        NametextField = new JTextField();
        NametextField.setBounds(10, 47, 274, 20);
        getContentPane().add(NametextField);
        NametextField.setColumns(10);
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new Frame2());
        panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(20, 78, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }

    private class Frame2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if (actionCommand.contains(getName())); {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your name is: " + NametextField );
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
```

Comment: Your `main()` does nothing. Put `new Frame1();` there and if you do not have any bugs you'll see the result.

Comment: where's you getName() definition?

Comment: You are writing too much codes just to do what you wanted to do.

Comment: I see `if (actionCommand.contains(getName())); {` Be aware that the semicolon right there is probably _not_ what you want.

Comment: *" I know I am missing something obvious"* `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` would be a start.  Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your name is: " + NametextField );
```

You're basically saying *"Your name is this text field object"*. You'll want to use the `getText()` method of the text field to get the actual text

```
NametextField.getText()
```

---

- Note, `if (actionCommand.contains(getName()))` looks very suspect to me. I'm not sure this is what you want, though I have no idea what `getName()` returns. I think you want to check if the action command equals the action command of the button you want to check for. In which case you want `if ("Submit.equals(actionCommand))`
- Also note, as pointed out by @Takendarkk , the `;` after your parenthesis is negating the `if` statement, causing the action to be performed, whether or not the if statement is true.
- Also note, as pointed out by @MadProgrammer, stay away from the null layout. Learn to use LayoutManagers, and let them do the sizing and positioning for you. See more at [Laying out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- Also note, you should be following Java naming convention. variable names begin with lower case letters, using camel casing: `NametextField` → `nameTextField`